# Varnish is cached but Google Chrome showing not cached?

Tags: caching, magento2, varnish-4

I have installed Varnish and configured it as per as the guideline.
And when I try it `curl -I https://d-o-m-a-i-n.com` I get following which seems its working correctly.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2020 03:17:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Expires: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 03:17:03 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
Pragma: cache
X-Magento-Tags: cms_b_porto_homeslider_3,store,cms_b,cms_p_91,cms_b_porto_custom_notice_new,cat_p,cat_c_p_30,cat_p_22,cat_p_1,cat_p_34,cat_p_21,cat_p_41,cat_p_11,cat_p_39,cat_p_35,cat_p_33,cms_b_porto_footer_top_1_for_5,cms_b_porto_footer_middle_1_for_5,cms_b_porto_footer_middle_2_for_5
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Varnish: 33268 3
Age: 13957
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
X-Cache: cached
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

But when I check in Google Chrome header response I get followings where it shows Varnish is not caching and age is 0?

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20027
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2020 07:13:35 GMT
Expires: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 07:13:35 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: cache
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
X-Cache: uncached
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Magento-Tags: cms_b_porto_homeslider_3,store,cms_b,cms_p_91,cms_b_porto_custom_notice_new,cat_p,cat_c_p_30,cat_p_1,cat_p_22,cat_p_21,cat_p_11,cat_p_34,cat_p_41,cat_p_39,cat_p_35,cat_p_33,cms_b_porto_footer_top_1_for_5,cms_b_porto_footer_middle_1_for_5,cms_b_porto_footer_middle_2_for_5
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Varnish: 1704417
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Do you have any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the key for caching(vcl_hash)?
Check it and make sure there is no user agent involved.